# thoughts on Contemporary abstract algebra by Joe Gallian

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I was wondering if the book Contemporary abstract algebra was suitable for self study. I've heard from people that the level is somewhat low and that things such as polynomials in several variables, particularly theorems on symmetric ones. Also,ive heard that applications from abstract algebra to linear algebra are lacking as well. Is this true? if so, which books would you reccomend for abstract algebra self study?